# One VM across multiple partitions

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I have a 1TB hard drive which has 3 partitions on it. `D:` is 250 GB, `X:` is 300.63 GB and then there was an extra 380.88 GB unused (each is NTFS being used by a Windows 8 OS). `X:` has a 250 GB VirtualBox VM on it (.vdi file). I wanted to expand that VM so I extended the `X:` partition onto the unused 380.88 GB file and I thought it would simply make that partition larger.

Instead it changed the Disk to Dyanmic and now the `X:` disk is spread across 2 partitions (even though both are on the same disk). Is there anything wrong with this? Do I need to copy these files somewhere else, reformat the drive and then make sure there is only 1 partition for the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, reformat the `X:` drive so it uses the entirety of the space instead of being 'spanned' (which is what it sounds like you did). Though technically speaking the only thing this might affect is read times since the 2 partitions are being 'spanned' as 1 and you have a VERY large file across multiple HDD layers/partitions (possible higher read times at a low level).

At a high level it shouldn't effect anything since essentially all you did was increase the size of `X:` from 300GB to 680GB, so in all reality it's up to you if you want to take the time to move the VDI onto backup drive (which I recommend you do anyways) and then reformat/copy over VDI.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I moved the .vdi file to another disk and tried to start it from that disk but it gave me an error about the disk's UUID. If I reformat the drive and then move the .vdi file back over will I still have that issue?

Comment: The UUID is in the config file of your virtual machine. To have that error go away, remove the VDI from your Virtual Media Manager (which disconnects it from the VM) then simply re-add the existing VDI to the VM you removed it from (generating a new UUID)